# Access grub menu from locked out ubuntu lenovo edge 15

Tags: ubuntu, passwords, grub, lenovo-laptop, password-recovery

I have a single boot lenovo edge 15 with ubuntu. Unfortunately, installing Google's 2FA corrupted my password. Locking me out.

The fix requires accessing grub. The problem is that I have no way to access grub. I have tried the novo button, F2, F12, SHIFT, and ESC. No luck. Instead I either get just a black screen, or the system proceeds to ubuntu.

This may seem like a ask ubuntu question, however they redirected me here

Also, I would like to note: at no time does the Lenovo logo ever appear at boot strangely

Comment: Google's 2-step authentication is applicable to your **Google account only**. It has nothing to do with Grub or the firmware (BIOS/UEFI). You're confused also regarding Grub if you think the keys you tried - which are for accessing BIOS or UEFI settings - have anything to do with Grub. But again, you problem with your Google account has nothing to do with any of those things.

Comment: Use any live bootable media to boot from and fix the grub settings.

Comment: @Biswapriyo The *the system proceeds to ubuntu* suggests there's nothing to fix in Grub. This is a very confused user so better wait for some clarification before trowing suggestions in the air.

Comment: @gabrielagarcia I wonder if he is trying to get to grub to boot into single user mode similar. Im not sure.what this would accomplish though.

Comment: Have you tried.USB booting supergrub? Also, sometimes F10 or TAB will do you.

Answer (score 0):

The BIOS/UEFI utility can be accessed by pressing the key which is shown on the manufacturer's splash screen when the computer is booting. This is the <kbd>F12</kbd> key on many computers. The keys to press, such as <kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd>, differ on computers from different manufacturers.

```
Manufacturer    Models                                          Boot Menu Key      BIOS Key  
Lenovo          Desktops                                        F12, F8, F10       F1, F2    
Lenovo          Laptops                                         F12 or press Enter at the short Lenovo Screen in the beginning               F1, F2  
Lenovo          ThinkPad edge, e431, e531, e545, helix, l440, l540, s431, t440s, t540p, twist, w510, w520, w530, w540, x140, x220, x230, x240, X1 carbon            F12                F1
```

If pressing the <kbd>F1</kbd> key doesn't register the first time, try spamming <kbd>F1</kbd> in quick succession.